# Issue with httpcontext asp.net core after deploy to IIS

Tags: c#, iis-7, .net-core, asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-webapi

I have one problem with HttpContext.Session.
describe: 
- I run site from visual studio => everything is ok.
- but I publish site as debug mode, and host it on IIS.
- and I run that site => I can't use httpcontext
- error message : 'this.HttpContext.Session' threw an exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException

https://i.stack.imgur.com/vJusn.png

can anyone help? thanks.

Comment: Read the exception message & stack trace.

Comment: Could you please post your stack trace?

Comment: I edited and attached image stack trace. thanks.